# Java Length Unlimited AudioInputStream

Tags: java, audio, stream, javasound

I have a bunch of code that will, when run, produce procedural sound.  Unfortunately, it only lasts a few seconds.  Ideally it would run until I tell it to stop.  I'm not talking about looping, the algorithm to generate it provides 2^64 samples, at the moment, so it isn't going to run out within the foreseeable future.  The constructor for AudioInputStream takes a third input, which I could ideally just remove.  I could just provide a huge number, but that seems like the wrong way to go about it.

I thought about using SourceDataLine, but the algorithm ideally would be called on-demand, not running ahead and writing the path.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I've answered my own question.

Upon further research, using the `SourceDataLine` is the way to go, as it'll block when you've given it enough to work with.

Apologies for the lack of proper Javadoc.

```
class SoundPlayer
{
    // plays an InputStream for a given number of samples, length
    public static void play(InputStream stream, float sampleRate, int sampleSize, int length) throws LineUnavailableException
    {
        // you can specify whatever format you want...I just don't need much flexibility here
        AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(sampleRate, sampleSize, 1, false, true);
        AudioInputStream audioStream = new AudioInputStream(stream, format, length);
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audioStream);
        clip.start();
    }

    public static void play(InputStream stream, float sampleRate, int sampleSize) throws LineUnavailableException
    {
        AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(sampleRate, sampleSize, 1, false, true);
        SourceDataLine line = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(format);
        line.open(format);
        line.start();
        // if you wanted to block, you could just run the loop in here
        SoundThread soundThread = new SoundThread(stream, line);
        soundThread.start();
    }

    private static class SoundThread extends Thread
    {
        private static final int buffersize = 1024;

        private InputStream stream;
        private SourceDataLine line;

        SoundThread(InputStream stream, SourceDataLine line)
        {
            this.stream = stream;
            this.line = line;
        }

        public void run()
        {
            byte[] b = new byte[buffersize];
            // you could, of course, have a way of stopping this...
            for (;;)
            {
                stream.read(b);
                line.write(b, 0, buffersize);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess I'll accept this answer in two days...unless somebody else comes up with a better solution.